# How to use XSLT in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

[image]

I am new to XSLT coding in SharePoint, but I know that we can use XSLT coding to create a list view with more sty-lings.

I have a list named "**detailsOfEmployee**" with columns *title, name, Id, salary, company*.

I want to create a view with columns name,company,salary with a condition that salary is greater than zero. Now I am using SharePoint 2010 to create webpages. Can anyone please provide an example of xslt code for creating a list view or any link of a website which has a example with clear explanation.

Comment: You should always start from the code that SPDesigner generates, then customize it

Comment: Is that we have create a list view using content editor then have start editing it in share point designer  ???

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understood. Did you nest a ListView webpart within a content editor web part? Why didn't you add the LVWP directly in a webpart zone?

Comment: We can add LVWP as you told. But i want to customize my list view through XSLT, that is my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the page in Advanced edit mode, then in Split mode, click on the XSLTListViewWebPart tag.
The List View Tools tab will open. Click on Design > Customize XSLT > Customize Entire View.
At this point, the default XSLT code will be shown and you can start editing.

[image]

Comment: When i try to open my aspx page in share point 2010 designer it is not allowing me and it is asking choose some options like edit in browser, edit page layout.
How can i edit my aspx page in share point ?

Comment: @vinodkumar It means the page you're on is a publishing page. You can try detaching it from page layout, making your modifications, then re-attaching it

Comment: List View Tools tab is not visible in sharepoint 2010 even though after clicking on XSLTListViewWebPart tag.
I have added a screen shot in my question.